# Is different drivers loaded for crossfired GPUs normal?

Tags: drivers, gpu, crossfire

I have two Radeon 5850's in a crossfire setup, and I'm seeing some differences in GPU-Z for their drivers (the second doesn't have that "Catalyst 10.12") and what they say for Crossfire:

[image]
[image]

Is that normal? I am noticing the second GPU being used during games, so I would think that it's okay, but I thought I'd double check.

Comment: What field are you referring too? While you can set different drivers for separate devices in the device manager, your driver versions look like the same to me. The only difference I can see is that Catalysts runs on the first card...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm referring to, the Catalyst 10.12. What do you mean by "Catalysts runs on the first card"?

Answer (score 1):

The first seems to be your main, or Crossfire, card. That's all. Notice in ATI Crossfire how one says Enabled and the other says Disabled.

This is probably simply how the ATI Crossfire drivers differentiate the 2 cards and enable Crossfire mode. Nothing to worry about here.